# Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection with EmbeddedDerby

Tags: java, hibernate, derby

I'm using Embedded Derby **`Derby 10.15.2.0`**   with **`Hibernate  5.4.14`**

Driver and c3p0 jars are added to project classpath but don't know why I'm getting

> `ERROR: An SQLException was provoked by the following failure: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.NoGoodResourcesException: After checking so many resources we blew the stack, no resources tested acceptable for checkout. See logger com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool output at FINER/DEBUG for information on individual failures.`

And

> `Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection`

Here is `Hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyTenSevenDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby:/home/.netbeans/11.0/derby/clientieFX</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">app</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">app</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">APP</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">6</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout">3600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionTimeout">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">/* ping */</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">on_close</property>

        <mapping resource="com/clientie/pojo/Order.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/clientie/pojo/Client.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/clientie/pojo/Product.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/clientie/pojo/User.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried change properties but it doesn't work.
Why it is not able to connect ?

Comment: Derby 10.15 requires Java 9+. Are you running a high enough version of Java?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Yes running on JDK 11 LTS

Comment: @BryanPendleton well it is because connection is not establishing that I found db.lck in database folder. So I think embedded derby isn't best choice with hibernate. As you seen my previous question.

Comment: Oh, yes, that makes sense. Thanks for reminding me that the two questions are related.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Thanks to you too. So may I need to get back to MySQL

Comment: @BryanPendleton But I'm afraid cause Derby's performance is really good than any.